# Asking for some hints for this real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral

Justify the following equation:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{p-1}}{1-x}\log(\frac{1}{x}) dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+p)^2} $$ Where $p>0$

Comment: if you want to go for an overkill solution, differentiate the $\log$ of the product expansion for the gamma function w.r.t to $p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.
2. Motivate $\int\sum=\sum\int$.
3. At last, integration by parts.

Comment: I am having trouble justifying the interchange of integration and summation; why does $\sum x^{n+p-1} \log(1/x)$ converge uniformly? I tries the Weierstrass M test but it failed, or I made a mistake, and I am not sure how else to approach it.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 The easiest is to use [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions). Alternatively you can do the standard trick: consider $\int_0^r$ for $r<1$, then it is no trouble with Weierstrass test. After interchanging you will take $r\to 1^-$. At this point you may need to know that $\ln x\cdot \ln(1-x)$ is continuous at $x=1^-$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By using a classic geometric series result, one has
$$
 \frac{x^{p-1}}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+p-1},\quad |x|<1,
$$ then observing that
$$
\int_0^1x^{a-1}\ln  x\:dx= -\frac1{a^2}
$$ one gets the expected result with a termwise integration.